# How to implement a virtual keyboard

Tags: python, pyside2

We develop a Python PySide2 application (current Version) for an industrial PC with a touchscreen (Windows 10). For the number-inputs (QLineEdit) we need an virtual keyboard (the numeric keys a sufficient, like a numpad).

I know that "Qt Virtual Keyboard" classes like QVirtualKeyboardAbstractInputMethod but I don't find any PySide2 Python example.

1. How would you implement a virtual keyboard (on screen keyboard) with PySide2?
2. Should we use the "Qt Virtual Keyboard" classes or a "normal" widget with buttons to simulate the keys?

Comment: QVirtualKeyboardAbstractInputMethod cannot be implemented in python. One possible solution is to use Qt Virtual Keyboard: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-index.html Or as you say implement your own keypad with the Qt Widgets

Comment: Ok, thank you very much @eyllanesc!